# Golang - Dúvida sobre ponteiros

Tags: ponteiro, golang

Tenho uma struct chamada Calculadora, com duas propriedades: versao e autor. Pra poder instanciar essa struct já inicializando esses métodos, já que Golang não possui construtores, as várias dicas que encontrei na net indicam criar um método NewCalculadora() e depois usá-lo pra instanciar a Calculadora. O método ficaria assim:

```
func NewCalculadora() *Calculadora {
        return &Calculadora{autor:"Paulo Luvisoto",versao:1.0}
}
```

E todas as dicas indicam o uso de ponteiro, como está acima. Mas vi que assim também funciona:

```
func NewCalculadora() Calculadora {
        return Calculadora{autor:"Paulo Luvisoto",versao:1.0}
}
```

Minha dúvida é: qual o problema de usar dessa segunda maneira, sem usar ponteiro?

Comment: O Golang irá "converter" internamente, caso você use `func (c *Calculadora) ...`, então usar `&` seria preferível. Isso é, até onde eu sei.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A melhor definição que eu já ouvi sobre esse assunto foi a seguinte:

> Ponteiros servem para compartilhar.

Normalmente essa dúvida se resume à uma questão de semântica.

**Por exemplo:** Você cria um valor do tipo `Calculadora`.

```
calc := NewCalculadora()
```

Ok, você tem a sua calculadora (calc).

Você pretende/precisa mutar/alterar os valores desse tipo? (autor ou versao)

Não? Então retornar uma cópia é o suficiente.
Lembrando que em Go os argumentos são passados por valor (cópia).

No seu caso, se você quiser alterar algum dos campos desse tipo, você precisa de um ponteiro.

Um belo exemplo disso é o pacote `time`.

Veja a função [Time.Add](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add), apesar de você adicionar uma duração à um instante de tempo, você não está alterando aquela "instancia", mas sim está retornando um novo valor.

Indo na contramão, o pacote `os`, possui o tipo [os.File](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) que usa semântica de ponteiro.
Já que nesse caso é muito mais lógico você compartilhar um arquivo do que criar cópias.

Então, não tem problema algum em usar com ou sem ponteiro, tudo vai depender do que você pretende fazer.
Espero que isso ajude a resolver sua dúvida.

Comment: navossoc, acho que está começando a clarear. Por exemplo... se eu tenho uma struct com duas propriedades e quero fazer funções getters e setters pra essas duas propriedades, no caso dos getters não preciso de ponteiros. Mas no caso dos setters, sim, pois estarei alterando as propriedades. Procede?

Comment: É basicamente isso que você falou, com exceção dos tipos de referência que não precisariam necessariamente de um ponteiro para serem modificados, mas mesmo assim, você precisa ter cuidado extra na hora de manipula-los. Se você realmente quer usar a linguagem a sério, você vai precisar dar uma boa estudada para evitar surpresas desagradáveis no futuro (ainda estou aprendendo também).